# JS linking not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to make external JS file where I will make edits for web. But when I try to link, so some of commands work and others not. For example. Toggle works when I click, but when I click on link in menu, so that menu doesn't hide and don't use animation for scrolling.

Here is code: **but in jsfiddle it works fine** it doesn't work correctly when I try to make external script.js

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
   $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    })
 }); 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-link').click(function() {
      $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 250);
      $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open');
    });
}); 
 
$(document).ready(function($){       
     $('a').on('click', function(e){
           var $anchor = $(this).attr("href");
           var $hrefStart = $anchor.substr(0, 1);

           if ( $hrefStart == "#" ) {
               $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top
               }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

               e.preventDefault(); 
           } else {
               window.location.href = $anchor;
           }
     });
 })(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
 
}

.container {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}
header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block; 
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
 
}

.site-nav {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav--open {
 height: 100vh;
 opacity: 100;

}
.site-nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 
}
.site-nav li {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;

/* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}
.site-nav li:last-child {
/* border-bottom: none; */
}
.site-nav a {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
 
 color: white;
}
.menu-toggle {
 position: fixed;
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75em;
 top: .5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 background-color: #2ecc71;
 height: 3px;
 width: 1.75em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before {
 
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.hamburger::after {
 transform: translateY(3px);
 
}


.open .hamburger::before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
 transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
 
}
.open .hamburger {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#particles-js {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 
}
#about {
 height: 100vh;
 
 
}
#portfolio {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: blue;
 
}
#contact {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
}
h1.main {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
h2 {
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 5%;
 font-size: 2em;
  
}
a.logo {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #2ecc71;
}
span.home {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 1%;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
}
span.about {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 1%;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
}
a.about {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .site-nav a {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 
}
.show {
 
}

.text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#particles-js" class="logo"><h1 class="logo">Lorem <span>ipsum</span></h1></a>
        <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">Manipulations</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Works</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </header>
<div id="particles-js">
<h1 class="main"></h1>
<div class="text"><p>sssss</p></div>
</div>
<span class="home">Home</span>
<a href="#" class="about"><span class="about">About</span></a>

<div id="about">
         
</div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need of multiple `document.ready`.All code can go inside single `document.ready`

Comment: Have you check correct path which you are giving for external js files.?

Comment: How I said. Some of commands works in external JS but others no. For example toggle open works fine, but when I click on some of href in menu, so menu won't hide. When I copy whole JS to HTML, so everything works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this stripped version of your script... No need to use mutiple document.ready functions... and also no need to use jquery alias ('$') name in document.ready function if '$' is not conflict with any other library...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
 $('a').on('click', function(e){
       var $anchor = $(this).attr("href");
       var $hrefStart = $anchor.substr(0, 1);

       if ( $hrefStart == "#" ) {
           $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top
           }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

           e.preventDefault(); 
       } else {
           window.location.href = $anchor;
       }
 });
 $('.menu-link').click(function() {
    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 250);
    $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('open');
  });
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  })
 });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

body {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
 
}

.container {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #EBEBD3;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}
header::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block; 
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
 
}

.site-nav {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav--open {
 height: 100vh;
 opacity: 100;

}
.site-nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 
}
.site-nav li {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;

/* border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;*/
}
.site-nav li:last-child {
/* border-bottom: none; */
}
.site-nav a {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 99999;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
 
 color: white;
}
.menu-toggle {
 position: fixed;
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: .75em;
 top: .5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 background-color: #2ecc71;
 height: 3px;
 width: 1.75em;
 border-radius: 3px;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger::before {
 
 transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.hamburger::after {
 transform: translateY(3px);
 
}


.open .hamburger::before {
 opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
 transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(90deg);
 
}
.open .hamburger {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#particles-js {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 
}
#about {
 height: 100vh;
 
 
}
#portfolio {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: blue;
 
}
#contact {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
}
h1.main {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
h2 {
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 5%;
 font-size: 2em;
  
}
a.logo {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #2ecc71;
}
span.home {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 1%;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
}
span.about {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 1%;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
}
a.about {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .site-nav a {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 
}
.show {
 
}

.text {
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Doplniť neskôr">
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#particles-js" class="logo"><h1 class="logo">Lorem <span>ipsum</span></h1></a>
        <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#particles-js">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#about">Manipulations</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#portfolio">Works</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </header>
<div id="particles-js">
<h1 class="main"></h1>
<div class="text"><p>sssss</p></div>
</div>
<span class="home">Home</span>
<a href="#" class="about"><span class="about">About</span></a>

<div id="about">
         
</div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please copy whole code and try it in your PC ? Mean try to use menu. Open and click on some href. When you click menu should hide and page should move on that part. But it doesn't work in linked JS. When I use whole JS in html it works perfectly, but when I try to use it in external JS it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Yes i tried and its working fine... can you please open console window and check there is any error...

Comment: There is no error. It just don't close when I click on link and animation for scroll doesn't work as well

Comment: Only Error is in editor...in external JS it says ERROR: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]

Comment: did you add your scripts in 'script.js' file? or any other file?

Comment: I found problem. I just realised that I have mess in files, so theres was bad path to that JS xD i'm sorry. And thank you for your interest. I deleted all files which I don't need and everything looks good now. Rep +